# How can I get a 16x16 frame of pixels removed from a video using C++ AND OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I have some code typed up and what it performs currently is it will read a video input and export the all the pixel values for each frame to a text file. Where currently stuck and have been ripping my hair out to figure out is how to remove a 16x16 frame of pixels from the video during its export. So what I need to end up with is a text file of all pixel data from each frame, with a 16x16 of pixels removed from each frame of the video.

C++ is completely new to me so a lot of terminologies and ideas out there are really making this hard.

I know that something needs to be in the for loop. I just need it to remove that 16x16 frame of pixels from each frame of the video.

```
ofstream output("Output.txt");

// for loop to get every frame
for (;;)
{
    Mat frame;

    capture >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        break;
    }

    //convert to gray image
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // pixel value
    int grayValue;

    //get every data value per frame
    for (int r = 0; r < frame.rows; r++)
    {

        for (int c = 0; c < frame.cols; c++)
        {

            grayValue = frame.at<uchar>(r, c);
            output << grayValue << " ";
        }
        output << endl << endl;
```

Comment: A video is a raster, i.e. a grid that is H pixels tall and W pixels wide. You can't *"remove"* pixels from it because, by definition, you have to store a value at each location in the grid. So, when you *"remove"* your 16x16 chunk, what will be left in the raster? Black? White? A transparent hole?

Comment: Before outputting the value, check if `r`and `c` are inside the frame to be removed.

Comment: What is the size of each frame and which 16x16 grid do you want to write into text file?